# How to create new item for not created object

Tags: mysql, angular, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm creating new form in Angular I want create Invoice object and list of invoice-items for this Invoice object but before I create Invoice I must first create some Invoice-items. In database my Invoice-item have foreign key for invoice. How should I solve problem with invoice-item I don't want save this invoice-items on database because in case when someone create them and leave creating form for Invoice these items will be save on database without Invoice

Comment: Create a type for your invoice and invoice item and bind your form to it. These objects will store your data on the page which you may submit once a user clicks submit button.

Comment: Can you show any work you have done for it?